# Is there an ES6 syntax for React-Router HOC/withRouter?

Tags: react-router

Is there a way to use the ES6 `extend` feature with the React-Router "withRouter" component?

Something like this:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export default class  extends withRouter {
   ...
   //Use react router history prop to navigate back a page.
   handleSomeEvent() {
     this.props.router.goBack();
   }
   ...
}
```

Or am I stuck using the old composition pattern?

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
   ...
});
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's easy, see bellow (not saying you should redirect 2s after component was mounted... just an example).

BTW my version of react-router is 2.6 (2.4+ required for withRouter)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.router.push('my-url')
        }, 2000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>My Component</div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I guess this is the closest so far.  I didn't think about using the composition along with a named class.  I was hoping for `class MyComponent extends withRouter` but I think this will do for now.

Comment: it may look crazy, but it works fine. i even use it in combination with redux and with my "permission controller" higher-order component

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCampaigns })(AuthorizedComponent(Campaigns));`

Comment: @MarekJalovec In your example in the comment where would you put withRouter? Would it be: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCampaigns })(AuthorizedComponent(withRouter(Campaigns)));`

Comment: exactly, i've posted version where withRouter is included in AuthorizedComponent, sorry for that. the "full" definition for that component is `return connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(AuthorizedComponent));`. the order does not matter as long as the function returns new higher-order component.

Answer (score 5):

You could use it like this.

```
@withRouter
export default class  extends withRouter {
   ...
   //Use react router history prop to navigate back a page.
   handleSomeEvent() {
     this.props.router.goBack();
   }
   ...
}
```

But you would have to include [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy)

Comment: Official Babel docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators.html